# 100% Answered Questions - Wow!

Tags: discussion, community

I know it's not a competition and we shouldn't use it as a target and really 100% isn't really 100% but....

[image]

Wow - 100% answered questions on this site. OK I know there is still 9 without an upvoted answer. But still ...... I just wanted to post to celebrate this and thank everyone for all the answers. We've really tackled a lot and there is tonnes of good stuff here.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm glad we are generating timely answers, but more importantly I'm glad for the quality of answers and sense of community that this score doesn't reflect.

Comment: @Buddho absolutely. We have some great answers to some difficult questions. These numbers just tell part of it. I genuinely think we are creating a great resource for the internet, spreading the Dharma and building a great community. A bit self-congratulatory maybe but I think we are great.

Comment: I suspect it is a common feeling, but I feel immensely grateful to have the opportunity to not only learn the Dhamma but also to share what I've learned and understood. I am so glad this community exists.

Comment: Steadily growing :)

Comment: This is great. Congratulations to all beings on Buddhism SE.

Answer (score 4):

Since this question has no answer, I am giving an answer so you don't lose your 100% answered question award. I wouldn't want to cause a paradox. :)